# Access tweek.less value in Squarespace

Tags: css, less, squarespace

I am modifying the Native Template for a client. I have the tweek.less 'Tweek' set up as follows:

```
 // tweak: { "category" : "Sidebar", "type" : "checkbox", "title" : "Vertical Line", "value" : "false", "target" : "aside#sidebar", "property" : "border-left", "id" : "left-border" }
 @verticalLine: 1px solid #B4C9DE;
```

I am attempting to target a property when the client changes the checked value in the CMS as follows:

```
 #left-border:not(:checked) * aside#sidebar  { border-left: none; }
```

Is there documentation on how to access that value? and relate it to the element/style that I want to change? Am I setting up the selector properly in order to get to aside#sidebar?

Comment: Squarespace makes a class based on the title of the tweek. So, the class is vertical-line. Access the aside like this. body.vertical-line aside#sidebar. Set the tweek like this: ``` @verticleLine: none; 
body.verticle-line aside#sidebar {
    border-left: 1px solid #B4C9DE;
}   ```

Answer (score 0):

The best way to access a Tweak value is by grabbing it via JavaScript. Each and every Tweak value can be retrieved by a `getTweakValue()` method. Using it is as simple as storing the value and writing a JavaScript function to handle the execution of your requirement:

`var tweakValue = Y.Squarespace.Template.getTweakValue('verticalLine');`

Comment: Where did you find the documentaition for that? 'getTweakValue'